# IOS DEV: Should I be concerned if the Main.storyboard layout looks different from the actual layout?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

So for my app, the tableview layout in the iOS simulator when I click run is CORRECT and as I intend. However the layout is not always 100% the same when I view the layout of the tableview in Main.storyboard. When I refresh Xcode(i.e. quit and restart app), the layout of Main.storyboard is what I intend. However, if I play around with orientations/diff iOS devices within Main.storyboard, and then return to my original device, the layout looks incorrect (even though supposedly the math/measurements are correct). Do I need to be concerned?

For reference I followed the instructions of https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/ EXACTLY to make a cell (instead of an image, I used a button though). And here is an image of my iPad simulator https://drive.google.com/file/d/152scJF6h12amh-AAycDqpe6TXOzN2y-H/view?usp=sharing vs the main.storyboard simulator https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NvUfMVLk08S8qH4mFraRsQYbDzPdjaBG/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

> However the layout is not always 100% the same when I view the layout of the tableview in Main.storyboard.

It sounds like you might have some missing or incorrect constraints. Take a look at the little yellow arrow icon to the right of "View Controller Scene":

[image: storyboard editor detail]

That icon tells you that there are some issues that you need to resolve. Click it and you'll get a list of the particular issues and your options for fixing them.

> Do I need to be concerned?

The risk, of course, is that under some circumstances your view *won't* draw the way you want it to. Start by fixing the issues that Xcode is pointing out, and then test on lots of different devices (or simulators) as you can, in all the possible geometries you might encounter (different screen sizes, orientations, split view, etc.).

Comment: I checked the changes listed in View Controller Scene and those are unrelated to the box and title/subtitle positioning that I was inquiring about. Also upon quitting and restarting Xcode Main.storyboard displays as expected for the current device it was set to, but not after I play around with the different devices on Main.storyboard, so this might be a glitch... Anyway thanks for your help!